# pandas SettingWithCopyWarning, not fully understood

Tags: python, pandas

I've read multiple SO questions and https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ which tells how to fix it however I still don't fully understand this concept.

so I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
    user_id distance(km)    duration
0   251.0   0.554358        '00:03:12'  
1   270.0   0.861835        '00:04:12'  
2   192.0   0.701571        '00:05:12'  
3   192.0   0.453691        '00:01:12'  
4   192.0   0.192449        '00:07:12'
```

For each duration I am going to convert it to seconds which is done by

```
dd_df["duration"] = dd_df["duration"].apply(lambda row:row.total_seconds())
```

or

```
dd_df["duration"] = dd_df["duration"].loc.apply(lambda row:row.total_seconds())
```

Both giving we SeetingwithCopyWarning.

according to the blog mentioned, this error arise when there is chaning assignment. I am assigning new df dd_df['duration'] and using apply therefore chaning assignment, So I've tried

```
`dd_df.loc[dd_df["duration"].apply(lambda row: row.total_seconds())]`
```

giving me Error:

```
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

Also isn't df.loc[:] also grabbing a copy of dataframe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dd_df is a slice of another dataframe right? You should use copy. Example dd_df = other_df.loc[1:20].copy(). Otherwise, you are modifying other_df when executing: dd_df["duration"] = dd_df["duration"].apply(lambda row:row.total_seconds())

Comment: Can you show how dd_df is defined?